# Can an aws lambda function make a post to a endpoint that is in a private network?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, vpn, aws-direct-connect

I want to know if is possible that a lambda function access to an endpoint that is in my private network, and that is not exposed to internet.

I was thinking use AWS Direct Connect to make a VPN between my private network (on premise) and AWS region; but i can't find any example on how configure the VPN on the lambda function.

Thanks you very much

Comment: Lambda functions can be launched in a VPC. You can have a VPN connection between on-prem and your VPC.

Comment: Is your private network on AWS or on prem?

Comment: @helloV my private network is on premise

Comment: @KrishnaKumarR Is an option, but my goal is to build a native serverless app. I don't want to manage EC2 instances. And this app need some data that is provided by an internal service in our private network

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how I would solve,

Create a VPC in AWS. Configure the lambda to run in that configured VPC.
Create a VPN Connection to your VPC. Now your private resources will be available to your Lambda.

**Documentation on running Lambda in your VPC:**

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-access-resources-in-a-vpc-from-your-lambda-functions/

**VPC VPN Configuration:**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_VPN.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: this lambda function, if run in a VPC context, can be triggered by a kinesis event?

Comment: I did verify the configuration we used, it did work with Kinesis and HTTP trigger as well. All configuration related to those are taken care by the cloud.